# how to align multiple div horizontaly

Tags: css, html

This is what I have done till now.

```
<div style="overflow:visible;width:1050px;border:1px solid green;height:50px;margin-left:115px">
<div style="border:1px solid red;position:absolute;width:730px;">

<br/><br/><br/>

<div class=''><div class='tagstyle'>FRESHER</div><div class='tagstyle'>IT JOBS</div><div class='tagstyle'>2013</div><div class='tagstyle'>BANGALORE</div></div>


<!----- left --->

<div>
<div style="border:1px solid blue;height:900px;position:absolute;width:340px;margin-left:735px;">

<!------ right --->
<div>
</div>
```

Problem is, right side div going downward, when left side div has any content.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Would you like a standard blog layout with header, main content and sidebar?

Comment: I have shared screenshot of problem. You can see, right div should be in same position of left div, but it move downward, when left div have some content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha! Saw your edit now! It's really simple with some css3 table display properties, but that doesn't work in old browsers.

However, you could use some simple css to make a standard blog template with sidebar, header and main content:

```
<style>
    .body-wrapper {
        position:absolute;
        top:20px;
        left:50%;
        width:900px;
        margin-left:-450px; /* Half the width (negative) */
        background:red;
    }

    .header {
        position:relative;
        width:100%;
        height:100px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
        background:blue;
    }

    .main {
        float:left;
        width:70%;
        background:green;
    }

    .sidebar {
        float:right;
        width:30%;
        background:yellow;
    }
</style>

<div class="body-wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        Header!
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        Content!
    </div>
    <div class="sidebar">
        Sidebar!
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a jsFiddle as proof: http://jsfiddle.net/Kepk9/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another answer!

If you just would like to position divs after each other, you could set them to display:inline-block, like this:

```
<style>

    .inline {
        display:inline-block;
    }

</style>

<div class="inline">
    Labalodado
    <br/>multiline content
</div>
<div class="inline">
    Less content
</div>
<div class="inline">
    Another div
    <br/>with
    <br/>multiline content
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code doesn't work is really simple actually. I made some other answers first because I think that they are a better approach.

**position:absolute doesn't automatically move the item to {0,0}**

You have to set `top:0px` by yourself.

Oh.. and there are some mistakes in your code too, but just go with one of my other too answers and you'll be fine :)